# How to calculate the average time of the checkout process?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the average time our customers spend during checkout process using Google Big Query.

As I am very new to SQL and BQ, I am running the following code trying to get the timestamp for checkout start, timestamp for checkout completion and then calculate the average.

```
SELECT
month, chekout_start as Checkout Started, 
time_to_transaction as Checkout
FROM ((SELECT 
     MONTH(TIMESTAMP(date)) AS month,
     TIME(AVG(TimeToCheckout)) AS time_to_transaction
  FROM (
     SELECT 
       date,
       fullVisitorId,
       timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000)) as start_time, 
       timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000 + hits.time*1000)) as hit_time,
       (TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000 + hits.time*1000))) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000)) ) ) AS TimeToCheckout
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([data.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31')))
     WHERE totals.transactions>=1
       )
GROUP BY month) transaction
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
     MONTH(TIMESTAMP(date)) AS month,
     TIME(AVG(TimeToCheckout)) AS checkout_start
  FROM (
     SELECT 
       date,
       fullVisitorId,
       timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000)) as start_time, 
       timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000 + hits.time*1000)) as hit_time,
       (TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000 + hits.time*1000))) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(timestamp(integer(visitStartTime*1000000)) ) ) AS TimeToCheckout
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([data.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-12-31')))
     WHERE (hits.page.pagePath = 'checkout/buy')
       )
GROUP BY month
) checkout_start
ON transaction.month = checkout_start.month)
ORDER BY month ASC
```

The desirable outcome looks like:

[image]

However, I am getting the error 'Encountered "  "transaction "" at line 18, column 17. Was expecting: ")" ...'. Can you please have a look at my code and explain what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  What is `CONCAT`?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: hey @GordonLinoff, CONCAT means concatenate. I use this command to concatenate the column containing the minute and second when the checkout is initiated (visit of the buy page) with the transaction timestamp. I have added the desirable outcome as well. We can use this chart instead: SELECT  FROM [bigquery-public-data:google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801] LIMIT 1000